# How can i put space Between two horizontally display button of UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uialertview

*This is may be simple question?*

But i dont know how to put space between two button of `UIAlertView`.
so please help me for How can i put space Between two horizontal button of UIAlertView.

**code of UIAlertView :**

Here in my **AlertView** i also add `UITextFiewd`

```
-(void)add:(UIBarButtonItem *) sender
{
    self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertViewTitle message:@"\n\n" delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancle"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Save",nil];

    self.alertTxtField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 55, 260, 35)];
    self.alertTxtField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.alertTxtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    self.alertTxtField.delegate = self;
    [alertView addSubview:self.alertTxtField];

    [alertView show];

}
```

**my screenshot :**

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: its possible only if you create your own AlertView, and not use the in built UIAlertView .!!

Comment: Deepjyoti Roy - how can i create my own AlertView ? please you have any idea then share it because i am new for iPhone :(

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with the `UIAlertView` class. As mentionied in the comments, you either have to code your own class from scratch or use one of the alternative `UIAlertView` classes found online, on sites such as [github](http://www.github.com). A quick google search brought this class up: [CODialog](https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog).

You might also think about whether you really want to put a space there, as the default appearance is what users see in basically all other apps.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose I think you need to add custom buttons to your AlertView as you did with textfield. You need to create two `UIButtons` and set appropriate frames and set it to the alertview as `subView`. Your method will change like:

```
-(void)add:(UIBarButtonItem *) sender
{
    self.alertView     = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    alertView.delegate = self;
    alertView.title    = alertViewTitle ;

    self.alertTxtField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 55, 260, 35)];
    // You need to allocate two buttons here and set the frame
    //add it to alerts sub view
    self.alertTxtField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.alertTxtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    self.alertTxtField.delegate = self;
    [alertView addSubview:self.alertTxtField];

    [alertView show];

}
```

Comment: yupp.. this is possible but without add Custom Button, it is possible or not ?? :(